# jQuery animate background-color not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a website with a navbar like this http://presentation.creative-tim.com/.  I want the navbar to change from transparant to a color when the user scrolls down the page.

I am using Bootstrap and jQuery. I am aware that jQuery can't animate background-color. So i am using the jQuery color plugin. 
This is my script:

```
   $(document).ready(function() { 
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75){
        $('.navbar').stop().animate({'background-color': 'rgba(0, 128, 128, 1)'},400);
    }
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 75){
        $('.navbar').stop().animate({'background-color': 'rgba(0, 128, 128, 0)'},400);
    }
});   
});
```

And this is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>test</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- color animations-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/color2.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color : rgba(0, 128, 128, 0); ">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" >Brand</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="white" href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="white" href="#">Over ons</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="white" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

I am stuck with this question for a couple of days now.  I read on this site that adding `$(document).ready` could help, but it still does not work. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox. But in IE the navbar stays transparent. I cant find the answer on Google. Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using ?

Comment: I am testing on IE 11(win 7)  I am going to try edge this evening

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a dumb mistake! IE 11 was restricting the execution of my JavaScript.

Comment: Is there a fix for this?